# how to get the time from bootstrap formhelper timepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I put in a bootstrap formhelper timepicker inside my webapp
however, I am having hardtime getting the time value from it

how to get the timevalue from bootstrap timepicker?

just doing `data.time=$("#fromTimeText").val();`
doesnt seem to work

http://vincentlamanna.com/BootstrapFormHelpers/timepicker.html

```
<div class="ltrClass bfh-timepicker" id="fromTimeText" style="text-align:center;">
<div class="bfh-timepicker-toggle rtlClass " id="pickupTime" data-toggle="bfh-timepicker">
<label for ="fromTimeText"></label>
<input type="text" id="fromTimeText" class="centralize" readonly>
<i class="icon-time"></i>
</div>
<div class="bfh-timepicker-popover" >
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr><td class="hour"><a class="next" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a><br>
<input type="text"  class="input-mini" readonly><br>
<a class="previous" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></a></td>
<td class="separator">:</td>
<td class="minute">
<a class="next" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a><br>
<input type="text" class="input-mini" readonly><br>
<a class="previous" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps show us some code?

Comment: i did, the post doesnt seem to update

Comment: I got the `data.time=$("#fromTimeText").val();` line, but would need some actual DOM.

Comment: finally got it to save, the strange part when i went to edit this post, the DOM was there... it just didnt show :/

Comment: any way, the timepicker object works just fine in showing the correct time, but i want to paste the time into another page, and i can't get its value

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: the javascript console says " data.time="" "

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35941/discussion-between-chaoticc-and-lena-bru)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was caused by a local condition: duplicate IDs on the HTML. Too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got duplicate IDs on both your `div` and your `input`. Change or remove the ID on your `div` and you're all set.